# Dynamic Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, javascript, post-meta

I am working on a custom invoicing system for a client.  I am looking for the best way to implement adding products dynamically to the invoice in the wordpress admin.  There are hundreds of products with prices and sku and such.  I think the best approach is to add a form with the following:

dropdown populated with all the sku's from the database, based on the selection, the item name and price are populated with ajax.

then based on the quantity entered, the total price is populated with javascript.

finally, a button that adds the info as a custom field entry.

I want to be able to add multiple entries using this same little form and then finally save the custom post type.

If anyone has done anything like this I would appreciate any direction.  I haven't listed any code, I know how to do the custom meta and all that in php, I am an extreme novice with ajax in the wordpress admin and not completely certain how to save and retrieve dynamically added custom meta.